# Can't edit the second user

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page where you can edit a user. If you click the edit button you get redirected to a page where you can edit that user. It works perfectly for the first person but when I click the edit button of the second user it does nothing. No errors nothing. You are not getting redirected to the page.

**My PHP**

```php
function getUsers($orgID, $type)
{
    require 'functions/conn.php';
    $sql = "SELECT users.*, parts.*, keuze.* FROM ((users INNER JOIN parts ON users.part_id = parts.part_id) INNER JOIN keuze ON users.keuze_ID = keuze.ID) WHERE users.org_id = '" . $orgID . "' AND users.active = '" . $type . "';";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<tr id="' . $row['user_id'] . '" class="changeUser">';

            echo '  <td>' . $row['fnln'] . '</td>';
            echo '  <td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
            echo '  <td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '  <td>' . $row['keuze'] . '</td>';
            echo '  <td>';
                echo '      <button class="button button-orange" id="btnChangeUser">Eind tijd</button>';

            if ($row['active'] == 0 || $row['active'] == 2) {
                echo '      <button class="button button-green" onclick="approveOne('.$row['user_id'].', '.$_SESSION['org_id'].')">Approve</button>';
            }
            echo '      <button class="button button-red" onclick="deleteFromRelation(' . $row['user_id'] . ');">Delete</button><br/>';
            echo '  </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

**My Jquery**

```
<script>

$("#btnChangeUser").click(function () {
    var userID = $(".changeUser").attr('id');
    window.location.href = "changeuser?user=" + userID + "";
});

function changeItem(userID) {
    window.location.href = "changeuser?user=" + userID + "";
}

</script>
```

What I expect is that if I click on the edit button of the second user it will redirect me.

**Edit**

the second row is the row I can't edit.
 [image]

Comment: Problem is that you are getting multiple elements with the same id `btnChangeUser`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen what do you mean? It only gets the id. the rest of the information will i get from a query inthe edit page

Comment: he means `for each { input id=a }` will create all of them with the same id - the event handler only allows for a unique id so only picks up the first.

Comment: The button with the text `Eind tijd` is generated for every user, correct? In that case all these buttons have the same `id` and that is a no no. try change `class="button button-orange" id="btnChangeUser"` to `class="button button-orange btnChangeUser"` and then `$("#btnChangeUser").click` to `$(".btnChangeUser").click`. Last you would have to change `$(".changeUser").attr('id')` to `$(this).closest(".changeUser").attr('id')`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you it works! can you explain why it works? I am not very good with jquery. If you put it as answer I can accept it an upvoted it

Comment: @Dharman yeah I know i'm going to change it right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign same id. It's rule violation.  Instead of `id` use `class` and `data-id` .

```
<button class="button button-orange" data-id="' . $row['user_id'] . '">Eind tijd</button>';
```

And to catch data-id use button class with `this`:

```
$(".button-orange").click(function () {
    var userID = $(this).data('id');
    window.location.href = "changeuser?user=" + userID + "";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick note: Avoid SQL Injections by preparing your SQL Queries :

PDO : https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Mysqli : https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection